# Não reconhece meu método createQuery

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, cdi

Estou com um projeto JSF2.2 com CDI, e configurei corretamente meu projeto para CDI, o que é de muito estranho é que o método createQuery não está sendo reconhecido, de outras vezes fez a mesma maneira de programar e nunca tive problema, mas agora estou tendo dificuldade.

Veja como está a figurar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é referente a esse trecho do código

```
categoriasRaizes = manager.createQuery("from Categoria",
        Categoria.class).getResultList();
```

Agora veja a minha classe Bean

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model.Categoria;
import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model.Produto;
import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.util.jpa.EntityManagerProducer;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroProdutoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Produto produto;

    private List<Categoria> categoriasRaizes;

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerProducer manager; //>>>>>> está sendo realizado injeção pelo CDI para fazer funcionar a o método inicializar

    public CadastroProdutoBean() {
        produto = new Produto();
    }

    public void inicializar() {


        categoriasRaizes = manager.createQuery("from Categoria",
                Categoria.class).getResultList();


    }

    public void salvar() {

    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public List<Categoria> getCategoriasRaizes() {
        return categoriasRaizes;
    }

}
```

Essa é a classe  EntityManagerProducer

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.util.jpa;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public EntityManagerProducer() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidoPU");
    }

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        manager.close();
    }


}
```

Não era para está dando esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando utilizar o `createQuery` da forma correta, porém no objeto errado.

Para corrigir, faça da seguinte forma:

```
EntityManager em = manager.createEntityManager();
categoriasRaizes = em.createQuery("from Categoria",
        Categoria.class).getResultList();
```

De toda forma, aconselho um método `getEntityManager` para a sua classe `EntityManagerProducer`, ficando algo como:

```
private EntityManager em;

public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if(this.em == null) {
        this.em = createEntityManager(); 
    }
    return this.em;
}
```

Dessa forma você garante a redução de overhead no consumo/criação dos entityManagers (Paleativamente, sugiro melhorias posteriores).